# Statements after the nextInt Line is not working

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I want the user to input the choice of their fruit to catch depending on the number of fruits he inputs. But the problem is that after the input on nextInt() the compiler stops compiling and skips the for loop.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FruitBasket {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    String select;

    System.out.println("Catch and eat any of these fruits: (Apple, Orange, Mango, Guava");
    System.out.print("How many fruits would you like to catch? ");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();

    for (int i = 1; i >= num; i++) {
        
        System.out.print("Choose a fruit to catch. Press A(apple), O(orange), M(mango), G(guava) ");
        System.out.print("\nFruit " + i + " of " + num + ": ");
        select = s.nextLine();
        stack.push(select);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure about that greater-than sign in the for loop?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i >= num; i++) ` - unless num is 1 or less

Comment: *the compiler stops compiling* - lazy compiler

Comment: thanks for the answer. just a beginner sorry